# How to create a android layout like this?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

How to create a layout like this in android studio.

Image as background + text centered horizontally and vertically + buttons:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a **RelativeLayout** and place all the elements accordingly to the others.

Something like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/centered_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_right_container"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <!-- the stuff bottom right -->

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to make the @+id/centered_text in the middle of ImageView?

Comment: Got it! i've added imageview and textview in another relative layout and give a fixed height

Comment: @OssamaBenallouch you should avoid fixed heights. Look into scaleTypes for ImageView and RelativeLayout paramaters (like centerInParent, used for the TextView). The combination of those should allow for better scaling.